# Affected Rows returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

So, I have been trying to fix this problem for 2 hours now, and I always get the error "Cannot read property affectedRows of undefined", when I try to delete a row from a mysql table. I have used the exact same code for another app and it was working well. But here I just can't figure out whats appening.

This is the code from the connection to the database and the actual function that deletes the row from the table dbService.js:

`

```
class DbService {

    static getDbServiceInstance() {
        return instance ? instance : new DbService()
    }

    
    async deleteTodoItem(id) {
        try {
            id = parseInt(id, 10); 
            const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const query = "DELETE FROM todoApp WHERE id = ?";
    
                connenction.query(query, [id] , (err, result) => {
                    if (err){
                        reject(new Error(err.message))
                    } 
                    resolve(result.affectedRows)
                })
            })
    
            console.log(response)
            return response === 1 ? true : false
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return false
        }
    }


}
```

`

Here is the code from the backend app.js:

`

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', (request, response) => {
  const { id } = request.params;
  const db = dbService.getDbServiceInstance()

  const result = db.deleteTodoItem(id)
  
  result
  .then(data => response.json({success : data}))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

`

And this is the code from the frontend, that deletes the item from the html element, index.js:

`

```
document.getElementById('todoItems').addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    if(event.target.className === 'deleteBtn') {
        deleteItemById(event.target.dataset.id)
    }
})

function deleteItemById(id) {
    fetch('http://localhost:3002/delete/' + id, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.success) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it, it was a problem on an attribute in an html element, that was making the id I was trying to get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this to criteria :

***Not Worked***

1st Possibility :

```
resolve(parseInt(parseIntresult.affectedRows,10))
```

2nd Possibility : Don't do Strict Equal

```
response == 1 ? true : false
```

**Another Solution :**

Try This One :

```
resolve(result['affectedRows'])
```

I hope this will help you, comment what happens after.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I tried both ways and I still get the same error, and I actually got more ideas based on your response tried them as well and I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: Okay, I've edited solution try that new solution.

Comment: Thanks again, but still not working I think the problem might be with what I'm getting from the query  because "result" is coming as undefined. I tried to just "resolve(result)", and I get : ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in  'where clause' .